# Is there any way to interact with open external application alert from a webpage using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web, popup, popupmenu

I tried switching tab that had popup using `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])`
and 
closing the first tab, but none of them worked
This is the code that I tried to accept the popup `driver.switch_to_alert().accept()`

[image: example:]

Comment: I think the reason why your switch_to_alert code won't work is because your execution stuck at the step when the pop up shows up on screen. In another word, your switch to code (or any code left) was not executed at all before that popup menu is gone. But ppl won't know the real issue unless your supply with more information, such as the url you are trying to scrape, so solutions can be tested.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling notifications through the chrome options?
This is what I had to use on my webscraping project:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
prefs = {'profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications': 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\Users\jeffg\Desktop\WebScraping\chromedriver.exe')
```

Documentation can be found here:

- https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/
- https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities

Answer (score 0):

It is not the usual javascript pop up. It is the browser pop up and you can't handle it with the code. I believe that you need to create a script with AutoIT to handle the same.